# How to secure web service api using OAuth 2.0 step by step in php

Tags: php, mysql, api, oauth

I have developed REST web service api in PHP and now I would like to secure it using OAuth 2.0. Basically I would like to provide token based access to the user who is accessing the web service api.

My application will be signed using Open Ids (Facebook, Twitter & Google+), I will get basic details like consumer_secret and ids from the open ids.

I have few queries :-

1) Do I need to create tables in my MySQL database and create token and store it with timestamp? And then whenever any user calls the api, we first check the token is valid or not and after that grant access to api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you will need to do that, but implement a OAuth server is a lot of work, better choose an existing package like https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php or http://oauth2.thephpleague.com/